# How do I build a .flatpak package file from a Flatpak manifest?

Tags: packaging, flatpak

I have a Flatpak manifest I'm submitting to Flathub, but I'd also like to build a .flatpak package file that I can redistribute myself. How can I go about doing this? I don't find anything in `flatpak-builder`'s command reference, and searching hasn't been fruitful either. To be clear, I don't expect the Flatpak to contain all of the necessary runtime, but I would like users who have installed the Freedesktop runtime from somewhere else to be able to install it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is referred to as "single-file bundles" in Flatpak's documentation, and the way you go about creating them is somewhat involved.

First, you need to build the Flatpak with `flatpak-builder`:

```
$ flatpak-builder build/ <path/to/manifest>
```

You may have to add `--force-clean` if `build/` already exists.

After that, you need to export the result with `flatpak build-export`:

```
$ flatpak build-export export build
```

Finally, you can export the Flatpak single-file bundle itself:

```
$ flatpak build-bundle export example.flatpak <Flatpak app ID>
```

If you want Flatpak to automatically fetch missing dependencies from a remote repository, you can add the `--runtime-repo` option. Here's an example where I'm using Flathub as the runtime repo:

```
$ flatpak build-bundle export example.flatpak <Flatpak app ID> --runtime-repo=https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

You can read the official documentation here, which has some information not covered here about e.g. installation: https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/single-file-bundles.html